# Identify a TV series episode where two friends are trapped at 'eternity party'

Tags: story-identification, tv

Old TV series episode: starts off with a host talking and then goes into a mini-story

- Two friends go to a party. One friend goes inside while the other waits in the car.
- After a while the friend in the car decides to go find his friend and as he walks up to the house, some weird hobo guy scares him into the house where the party is going on.
- He soon realizes its an 'eternity party' that no one can leave.
- He finally escapes (somehow) and sees himself walking into the house again and tries to stop himself but just ends up scaring himself into the house.
- It turns out that he was the weird hobo guy all along, creating a stable time loop.

Comment: When were you a kid? Was it in English? What country were you in? Did the episode seem to be linked to a larger series, or was it something more like The Twilight Zone or The Outer Limits? Was it in color? Do you remember any names of the characters? Did it seem to be aimed at any age group (e.g.: Are You Afraid Of The Dark was aimed at kids. Tales From The Crypt was aimed more at older viewers)

Comment: around the 90's and yeah it was an english series, in south africa, i'm not sure if it was linked to anything, also it was in colour, it was definitely aimed at more at adult viewers as the scenes in the house and everything was very adult based.

Comment: Sounds like something from the Bradbury Theater series, though I can't find an episode with this description.

Comment: So what you're saying is that there ain't no party like a time loop party, 'cause a time loop party literally don't stop.  Sorry, some parts of this sound familiar (a little like Primer, even).  I'll see what I can dig up...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After this question triggered memories of the exact episode, I did some searching and was able to find it. It is an episode entitled 'Party on' from the show [Dark Realm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Realm.), hosted by Eric Roberts.

Comment: [Jarvis!?](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0195439/)

Comment: OH MY FREAKING GREATNESS!!!!! THIS IS IT,

Comment: I am so happy right now, i thought i was loosing my mind, i even gave up, and then a hero comes along, this is exactly it, thank you so much,